# high side output of IR2110

Tags: mosfet-driver

i'm new here and not English native. i'll be very appreciative of pointing out my grammar errors.
i designed a new topology with four MOSFETs which low two operate as switches in 100kHz and high two are constant on.

however, the high side output is always low while the bootstrap capacitor is 15 volt. when i exchange the PWM signal, low side is constant on and high side is 100kHz switching signal, both low side and high side works.
[image]

### [image]

here are the layout and waveform. the dark blue is low side output and the light one is high side output. the MOSFETs are C3M0065090
[image]
[image]

Comment: Good heavens! Right to left schematic direction! Show waveforms. What duty-cycle are you running?

Comment: duty cycle is 60% and 100kHz. the low side output is normal PWM with expected values, high side output is always zeros.

Comment: Show oscillograms. Show layout.

Comment: Hi Rust, welcome to EE.SE! In your question, you mention 4 MOSFETs, but in your schematic I only see 2 gate drives. Can you improve your schematic to include the actual MOSFETs, and make it clear what are inputs and what are outputs? You should also put component designators (such as R1, C3, etc) in your schematic so people (including yourself!) can easily refer to specific components. Also tell us what MOSFETs are you using? Finally, I edited your post a little bit for grammar and style. Feel free to have a look and edit it further :)

Comment: What you need is a dedicated high-side supply rail, say from an auxiliary supply (like a small flyback converter) and a standard driver IC. This will allow you control over the gate plus allow you to keep it on as long as you wish.

Comment: indeed this topology is applied in a ac-dc converter . i need the two MOSFETs are constant on in a long period and operates as switches in another long period.

Comment: Listen to Adam, you need a floating supply to give you ~15 V on top of your positive supply rail.

Comment: @winny you mean i need another VCC(15V) ? could you make it clearer or give an example ?

Comment: @Rust http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva444/slva444.pdf

Comment: @winny i've provided an floating 15 for high side, by the diode Db and 0.33uF capacitor. and my question is that why the high side output is always zero instead of 15V. i know there are some other methods to achieve high side continuous on, but i think IR2110 should achieve this too.

Comment: @Rust Show updated schematic.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do always on for the high side unless you supply an external bootstrap voltage 12V or so greater then the high side source voltage, this should be obvious if you think about how the bootstrap cap and diode is supposed to work.

In fact most drivers will force the high side off if adequate voltage is not present across the boostrap cap to avoid accidentally running the high side in its linear region.

Comment: but the bootstrap capacitor voltage is 15V and i have done this in perf board with IR2110

Comment: Not 15V relative to ground, 15V relative to the high side mosfets source.... This is a charge pump and only works when the high side if off sufficiently often for the boost cap to recharge via the diode. You have 10k connected gate/source and a 0.33uF boost cap, so how long can the high side stay on before the charge on that cap becomes insufficient to hold the gate solidly above threshold?

Comment: @Rust Show waveform/oscillogram of that!

Comment: @winny i shown them in the answer below because i cannot put more than two pictures in the question, i'm sorry

Comment: @DanMills the 0.33uF bootstrap capacitor's voltage is 15V . it's stable .